# Power Pivot Data Model error

Tags: powerpivot

I am currently working on a Power Pivot Data Model and came across an error

> "duplicate values in linked table, Many to one relationship"

I am confused and stuck in the data model. For reference here I am attaching the image.

Answer (score 0):

Did not see an image, but am familiar with the message.

You have linked to a field in the lookup table that has at least one duplicated value.

Check first if you have linked to the correct field in the lookup table.

If not, just delete the relationship and try again. If so, you can check for duplicate values in a column by using Power Query.

Import you table into Power Query, remove all columns except the linking field column. Add a custom column that only contains the value of one.

Next group by your linking field and sum the 1's in the custom column. Filter out any sum that is just 1. What's left are the duplicated values for you linking field and the custom column tells you how many times the linking field value was found.